# simple useReducer for learning

Tags: reactjs, use-reducer

I'm learning the useReducer from official web and my code doesn't work ok, Im not sure how initialCount should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return { count: state.count + 1 };
      break;
    case "decrement":
      return { count: state.count - 1 };
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const UseReduceExample = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialCount );

  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>+</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default UseReduceExample;
```

Comment: did you add `const initialState = {count: 0};`?

Comment: no I didn't, does initialState need to have all values that we are passing with reducer?

Comment: no, but in your case, you are using increment/decrement from the state. so the must-have initial value for `state.count`

Comment: “does initialState need to have all values that we are passing with reducer?”  As a best practice, yes. @Muhammad is technically correct that there are situations where you can get away with an incomplete initial state.  But as a rule of thumb, “initialState should have all the values that you are passing to the reducer” is a pretty solid guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your initial state, see the below snippet.

```
 import React, { useReducer } from "react";


const initialState = {
  count: 0
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return { count: state.count + 1 };
      break;
    case "decrement":
      return { count: state.count - 1 };
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

const UseReduceExample = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrement" })}>-</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default UseReduceExample;
```

Comment: Thanks! I see so it's like default state that will use on first render? I assume useReduce re-renders when we change the values?

Comment: Yes @Norby , basically the method triggers and catches by useReducer and dispatch the updated state. If it helped you kindly vote and accept so it will be helpful for future references :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const initState = {
   count: 0
}
const reducer = (state=initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return { count: state.count + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { count: state.count - 1 };
    default:
      return state
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this better create a separate file and call it how you want ex MainStore. Then add state logic like this:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';

export const MainContext = createContext({});

export const initialState = {
  increment:'',
  decrement:''

};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
     case "increment":
      return { count: state.count + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { count: state.count - 1 };
    default:
      throw new Error('Action type must be defined');
  }
}

const MainStore = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <MainContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </MainContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MainStore;
```

And you wrap each component that will use this state like this.

```
    <MainStore>
      <UseReduceExample  />
      <AnotherComponent />
    </MainStore>

    And to use state and dispatch inside those components do it like this.

      import React, {useContext} from 'react'
      import { MainContext } from 'path/to/store/MainStore';
    
      const UseReduceExample = () => {
      const [state, dispatch] = useContext(MainStore);
    
      return (
        <>
          Count: {state.count}
          <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "increment" })}>+</button>
        </>
      );
    };

export default UseReduceExample;
```

Comment: are you sure that your example is working?